Violating Interface Segregation Principle (ISP) because of fat module
I'm working with TMDB API, This API has 2 improtant endpoints one for movies and the other for series.
right now working on movies, so i made an abstraction layer (module) to get data from that API
the question is, does that module violate ISP? it seems fat module but i think it conforms to Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) which implies that it's not violating ISP.
abstract class BaseMovieRepository{

  Future<List<Movie>> getNowPlaying();
  Future<List<Movie>> getPopular();
  Future<List<Movie>> getTopRated();
  Future<List<Movie>> getUpcoming();

  Future<List<MovieImage>> getMovieImages({required int movieId});
}


Who calls the BaseMovieRepository? Does each caller need all five methods? If so, then the ISP is satisfied. See also: In SOLID, what is the distinction between SRP and ISP?

Look at BaseMovieRepository clients, if at least one client of BaseMovieRepository does not use all the methods of BaseMovieRepository, then you violate the interface segregation principle (ISP) (most likely you are violating the principle).
I would like to draw your attention first of all to the open–closed principle (OCP). If you need to add a new method, say getComedy(), and you want to add that method to BaseMovieRepository, then you are violating the OCP.
A possible solution may be the following approach:
abstract class Movies {
  Future<List<Movie>> list();
}

abstract class Movie {
  Future<List<MovieImage>> images();
}

class PopularMovies implements Movies {
  // fields and constructors
  Future<List<Movie>> list() {
    // implementation
  }
}

class TopRatedMovies implements Movies {
  // fields and constructors
  Future<List<Movie>> list() {
    // implementation
  }
}

class UpcomingMovies implements Movies {
  // fields and constructors
  Future<List<Movie>> list() {
    // implementation
  }
}

// etc.

